# XML to Objects mapper

Tags: ruby, xml, orm, dtd

I am trying to make one application file format parser & generator. Application uses xml files with custom DTD. Currently I am thinking about writing object mapper with `nokogiri` to parse xml to objects and use these object to generate xml back. I have tried HappyMapper and xml-mapping but they didn't utilize full xml format. So Currently now I have made this but I think it is bit bad design.

http://pastie.org/5393012

Comment: I am searching for best way to do it. Now I am doing like this: https://github.com/gcds/libeagle

Comment: Please include your source code in the question, rather than a link to it. If/when the link breaks your question will not be very useful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use C# with XMLSerilaizer, it is the best. Here is the example:

```
---------------just a lot of entity ----------------------
using System;
namespace BuilderSerialization {
public class Address {
public Address() {}
public string Address1;
public string Address2;
public string City;
public string State;
public string Zip;
public string Country;
} }
using System;
namespace BuilderSerialization {
public class Author {
public Author() { }
public string FirstName;
public string MiddleName;
public string LastName;
public string Title;
public string Gender;
public Address AddressObject;
} }

namespace BuilderSerialization {
public class Book {
public Book() { }
public string Title;
public Author AuthorObject;
public string ISBN;
public double RetailPrice;
public string Publisher;
}}
-------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
namespace BuilderSerialization {
class TestClass {
static void Main(string[] args) {
Book BookObject = new Book();
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Book));
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("booktest.xml");
BookObject.Title = "Practical LotusScript";
BookObject.ISBN = "1884777767 ";
BookObject.Publisher = "Manning Publications";
BookObject.RetailPrice = 43.95;
BookObject.AuthorObject = new Author();
BookObject.AuthorObject.FirstName = "Tony";
BookObject.AuthorObject.LastName = "Patton";
BookObject.AuthorObject.Gender = "Male";
BookObject.AuthorObject.AddressObject = new Address();
BookObject.AuthorObject.AddressObject.Address1 = "1 Main Street";
BookObject.AuthorObject.AddressObject.City = "Anywhere";
BookObject.AuthorObject.AddressObject.State = "KY";
BookObject.AuthorObject.AddressObject.Zip = "40000";
BookObject.AuthorObject.AddressObject.Country = "USA";
ser.Serialize(writer, BookObject);
writer.Close();
} } }
```

After that you get the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Book xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Title>Practical LotusScript</Title>
<AuthorObject>
<FirstName>Tony</FirstName>
<LastName>Patton</LastName>
<Gender>Male</Gender>
<AddressObject>
<Address1>1 Main Street</Address1>
<City>Anywhere</City>
<State>KY</State>
<Zip>40000</Zip>
<Country>USA</Country>
</AddressObject>
</AuthorObject>
<ISBN>1884777767 </ISBN>
<RetailPrice>43.95</RetailPrice>
<Publisher>Manning Publications</Publisher>
</Book>
```

Comment: The OP is looking for a Ruby solution.

Comment: if you consider ironruby as a kind of ruby solution, it still can work.